# Onesignal Webpush - single domain, multiple apps? How to target user?

Tags: onesignal

I have been trying to understand the onesignal api, but I haven't found a structure where I can do the following:

I have one single domain, let's say account.domain.com.

On that single domain I host multiple web apps:

```
https://account.domain.com/app.html?app=1
https://account.domain.com/app.html?app=2
https://account.domain.com/app.html?app=3
```

For each of those web apps I want to enable notifications. Keep in mind, **I want to send user notifications per app**.

So my questions are:

- Do I set up one app on OneSignal.com, and create a unique "tag" for
  each app the user uses?
- Or do I set up multiple apps on OneSignal.com and target the user
  that way? (I tested this option by changing the appId in the Web SDK, but once I subscribe on one page, I am subscribed on the other page as well - changing the appId doesn't work)

What's the best course of action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem that you might run into with this is that a user's notification permission in their browser is linked to the domain, not the URL. So if a user blocks notifications from one of your web apps in their browser settings, they will also end up blocking them from all of the others.

If that's fine with you, the best way to do this would be to create a single OneSignal app that represents all of the apps on your domain. You can then use OneSignal [tags](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/docs/data-tags) to mark which apps a user wishes to receive notifications from.

If you want to ensure that a user's permission is not shared between all your apps, you will need to place each app on its own subdomain (i.e. app1.account.domain.com, app2.account.domain.com). You can then use a seperate OneSignal app for each of these subdomains.